# Vector notation differences

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

There is a admittedly naive question that is nagging me that I can't quite seem to nail down an answer for, probably because I don't know the right way to phrase the question. There are two notations of vector representation that I'm seeing in tutorials:

$ a\vec{v} + b\vec{w} $

and

$ a_x\hat{i} + a_y\hat{j} $

Are these representations able to express the same vector? Are they meant to be used interchangeably? I understand unit vectors and the notation fairly well but I'm not connecting the dots between these two representations.

Comment: What are the contexts you see these two notations? Often $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ are reserved to refer to a canonical basis (e.g. the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$) whereas $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ are more often variable names for vectors. Depending on context, it might be that these are intended to be the same, but I'd suspect that they are not meant to be related.

Comment: this is just different basis: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/change-of-basis/v/linear-algebra-coordinates-with-respect-to-a-basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not express the same vector per se (but they can of course by taking the unit vectors $\vec{v}=\vec{e}_1$ and $\vec{w}=\vec{e}_2$). $\vec{v},\vec{w}$ can express *any* vector (let's work in the $2$-dimensional case), so
$$a\vec{v} + b\vec{w}=a\begin{pmatrix}
  v_1 \\
  v_2 
 \end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}
  w_1 \\
  w_2 
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  av_1+bw_1 \\
  aw_2+bw_2 
 \end{pmatrix}$$
while $\hat{i}, \hat{j}$ express *unit* vectors (because they represent standard basis vectors), so
$$a_x\hat{i} + a_y\hat{j}=a_x\begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 
 \end{pmatrix}+a_y\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  a_x \\
  a_y 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Not just unit vectors, i.e. vectors of norm 1, but _standard basis vectors_!

Comment: That's actually pretty important to note. I will put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A vector has components.  If we are working in a 3 dimensional space, we often denote those components as x, y, and z.  So a vector $a$ could be $a=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$.  Another way to write this is $a_x \hat{i} + a_y \hat{j} + a_z \hat{k}$.

We can multiply a vector by a scalar.  So $k a$ is equals to $(k a_x,k a_y, k a_z)$.

We can add two vectors.  So $a+b$ is $(a_x+b_x,a_y+b_y,a_z+b_z)$.

Note: in a two dimensional space, you could just use $x$ and $y$.  This explains the notations you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

> $ a\vec{v} + b\vec{w} $

This is a linear combination of the vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$,
using two scalars $a$ and $b$.

> $ a_x\hat{i} + a_y\hat{j} $

This is also a linear combination, but it is special in two regards:

1. $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ are two special vectors, the unit vectors in $x$-direction and $y$-direction.
2. $a_x$ and $a_y$ are special scalars, they are the coordinates of vector $\hat{a}$: 
   $a_x = \hat{a} \cdot \hat{i}$ and $a_y = \hat{a} \cdot \hat{j}$

If $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are linear independent and the vector space has two dimension, then they can serve as basis vectors of a (in general not orthogonal) coordinate system. In that case $a$ and $b$ can be interpreted as coordinates of the same vector $\hat{a} = \vec{a}$.